# Let f be an analytic function in the disk ... Prove that

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, cauchy-sequences, complex-integration

Let $f$ be a function analytic in the disk $D={z:|z-1-i| \leq 4}$ that satisfies $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z$ in $D$.

Prove that $|f^{(3)} (1-i)| \leq \frac{3}{4}$.

Hint: apply Cauchy's Integral Formula to a circle centered at $1-i$

---

I know that if a function is analytic then the complex derivative exists at every point.  I also know that the disk is a circle centered at $1-i $ with a radius of $4$. I would like help starting and completing this problem.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation after "Prove that"? Do you mean to say $f^{(3)}(1-i)$?

Comment: Given Cauchy's integral formula
$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z$$
Let $\gamma = \partial D$, choose $n = 3$, $a = 1-i$, and use the bound $f(z) \leq 1$ in $D$ to obtain
$$ f^{(3)}(1-i) \leq \frac{3!}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial D} \frac{1}{(z-(1-i))^4}\,\mathrm{d}z = \ldots$$ 
(by what theorem)?

Comment: Hi, yes that's how I meant for it to appear. I must have made a mistake when I originally typed it. Thankfully someone made the edit for me. I'm still learning how to type math using LaTex. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula is

$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}dz}$$

Now, for this example, $n=3$ and $z_0=1-i$.  If we take the contour to be parameterized by $z=1-i+\rho e^{i\phi}$, $dz=i\rho e^{i\phi} d\phi$, and $0\le \phi \le 2\pi$, then $f$ is analytic for values of $\rho \le 2$.   This is because $f$ is analytic when $|z-(1+i)|\le4$ and the circle $|z-(1-i)|= 2$ is contained in the region of analyticity.  Now, we can write for $\rho \le 2$

$$\begin{align}
f^{(3)}(1-i)&=\frac{3!}{2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(1-i++\rho e^{i\phi})}{\rho^{4}e^{i4\phi}} i\rho e^{i\phi} d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{3}{\pi \rho^3} \int_0^{2\pi} f(1-i++\rho e^{i\phi}) e^{-i3\phi} d\phi\\\\
\end{align}$$

Taking magnitudes of both sides we find

$$\begin{align}
|f^{(3)}(1-i)|&=\left|\frac{3}{\pi \rho^3} \int_0^{2\pi} f(1-i++\rho e^{i\phi})e^{-i3\phi} d\phi\right|\\\\
&\le\frac{3}{\pi \rho^3} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(1-i++\rho e^{i\phi})| d\phi\\\\
&\le \frac{3}{\pi \rho^3} 2\pi \max |f(1-i++\rho e^{i\phi})|\\\\
&\le \frac{6}{\rho^3}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since this is true for all $\rho \le 2$, then the supremum is of this latter bound is $6/2^3$.

Thus

$$|f^{(3)}(1-i)|\le \frac34$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) states
$$f^{(n)}(a) =\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz$$
where $\gamma$ is a circle lying in $D$.
The distance between the point of interest $a=1-i$ and the center $1+i$ of the disk $D$ is $2$, hence we can let $\gamma$ have radius $r$ slightly less than $2$ (and consider the limit as $r\to 2$).
We find with unit speed parametrization of $\gamma$
$$| f'''(a)|\le \frac{3}{\pi}\int_{t=0}^{2\pi r}\left|\frac{f(\gamma(t))}{r^4}\right|\,\mathrm dt\le \frac3\pi\frac{2\pi r}{r^4}=\frac 6{r^3}.$$
In the limit $r\to 2$ this gives us $|f'''(a)|\le \frac{6}{2^3}=\frac34$.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative way to prove this!